# Change autogenerated column type in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The underlying data has type Char and values "Y","N". How can I make the grid show checkbox column while preserving binding? I tried

```
private void grdScenarioList_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.Char))
        {
            // Create a new column.
            DataGridCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            column.Header = e.Column.Header;
            //column.Binding = (e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn).Binding; 

            // Replace the auto-generated column with the templateColumn.
            e.Column = column;
        }
```

It shows checkbox column but binding is lost. 
If I uncomment column.binding line I get an error saying that (e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn).Binding is null. Is there a way?
I have a CharToBooleanConverter class that I use for checkboxes in other places but I am not sure how to assign it here.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution

```
if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.Char))
        {
            DataGridCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            col.Header = e.Column.Header;
            Binding binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName);
            binding.Converter = new CharToBooleanConverter();
            col.Binding = binding;
            e.Column = col;
        }
```